# import library with angular2 - webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, babylonjs

I'm using [angular2-webpack](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack) starter, and I want to import a npm library, for example [Babylon js](http://www.babylonjs.com/). I'm doing like this

```
import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs/babylon';
```

And Babylon comes with a `d.ts` file, so I put at the beginning of the file

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.d.ts" />
```

Although I can use the library, Visual Studio Code marks as an error and says `Exported external package typings file 'node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.d.ts' is not a module.` and I cannot use the autocompletion that comes with the typings.
I'm new with webpack, so I don't know if I have to set something. My configuration is the one that comes with the starter.

Is that the correct way to import an external library? What else do I have to configure to get rid of that error and use the autocompletion?

Comment: I realized that without importing anything I can use the autocompletion, but then of course BABYLON is not defined. So I don't know how to import BABYLON and keeping the typings.

Comment: In the current preview release of babylonjs there is an additional module file (./dist/preview release/babylon.module.d.ts). When trying to use babylonjs in angular2 this way, I now get "Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.". Did you have success with meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
npm install babylonjs babel-types
typings install dt~babylon --save --global
typings install dt~babel-types --save --global
```

Then in your code:

```
var BABYLON = require('babylon');
```

Comment: What is `babel-types` for?

Comment: After galavanting around the SO and Github for solutions, this is the one that actually worked for me, without having to manually edit the npm package's d.ts file. And no, you don't need the babel typings.